# create dynamic rows and insert link in cell using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

can someone help me? where is the mistake? or how can I put a link in a `td`?

```
 var c = [];
 $.each(resp, function(i, item) {             
    var a = $('<a>');
      a.attr('title', "aaa");
      a.attr('rel', "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: 400}}");
      a.text("bbbbb");
      a.addClass('modal toolbar');

     c.push("<tr><td>" + item.libelle_client + "</td>");
     c.push("<td>" + item.date_debut + "</td>");
     c.push("<td>" + item.date_debut + "</td>");
     c.push("<td>" +a + "</td>");
     c.push("<td>" + item.date_fin + "</td></tr>");               
 });
```

using this I got this

RENAULT 2020-03-27  2020-03-27  [object Object] 2020-03-31

I like to have a link, not `[object object]`
Thank you

Comment: Can you show `resp`?

Comment: $response   = array();
        foreach ($services as $ligne)
        {
           $response[] = array(
              'libelle_client' => $ligne->libelle_client,
              'date_debut' => $ligne->date_debut,
              'date_fin' => $ligne->date_fin,
              'id' => $ligne->id
           );
        }

Comment: Did my answer not help you?

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
 c.push("<td>" + a[0].outerHTML + "</td>");
```

This is dirty, but should work.